# Contacts not synced where WhatsApp Contact exists

Tags: contacts, sync, whatsapp-messenger

1. I used tine20 via MS-Exchange to sync contacts to my android device
2. I added WhatsApp. Some contacts are from both (tine20 and WhatsApp). All is fine.
3. I removed (accidentally) tine20 account from android device
4. Added tine20 again
5. Contacts which don't have WhatsApp are synced perfectly
6. Contacts which have  WhatsApp are not synced. Information from tine20 is missing. Via tine20 web interface I can see that all contacts are in tine20

What can I do to get all contacts from tine20 on my device again?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself this way: since I hardly use WhatsApp. I just removed it from the contact sync accounts.

After some minutes all contacts from tine20 where visible on the android device again. I am happy.

Better solutions are still welcome :-)